# EF Core with Jaro-Winkler similarity distance algorithm

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, similarity, jaro-winkler

I want to search for strings in my db with some similarity distance algorithm like Jaro-Winkler. However EF Core cannot translate such expressions. So you cannot use an expression like below:

`query.Where(x => JaroWinkler.Similarity(x.Title, someText) > 0.5);`

My question is how can I implement this with EF Core? Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement algorithm in your db vendor SQL dialect and register it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping

Some db vendors have some comparisons algos or extensions for full-text search (i.e. [MS Sql DIFFERENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/difference-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or FREETEXT)

Or use in memory processing.